# How to exit from chroot

Tags: ruby, chroot

I can chroot with `Dir.chroot`

```
Dir.chroot("/var/chroot/mychroot")
```

But how can I return back from chroot?

Comment: Uhm, why not use a block? :-)

Comment: What do you mean? `Dir.chroot(path){ execution }` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The point of a `chroot` is that you can't get out. However, if you don't `chdir` to `/var/chroot/mychroot`, then you can still access the outside filesystem using `.`, and `..`

I don't know much Ruby, but here's the trick in Python:

```
/tmp$ sudo python
>>> import os
>>> os.chroot("/var")
>>> os.listdir("/")    # list our new root
['backups', 'log', 'opt', 'cache', 'spool', 'lib', 'local', 'run', 'lock', 'games', 'mail', 'tmp']
>>> os.listdir(".")    # list a directory outside our jail
['.X0-lock', '.ICE-unix', '.X11-unix']
>>> os.listdir("..")   # list the outside root
['lost+found', 'bin', 'mnt', 'boot', 'opt', 'scratch', 'var', 'proc', 'usr', 'etc', 'lib', 'srv', 'sys', 'media', 'root', 'selinux', 'vmlinuz', 'dev', 'tmp', 'home', 'sbin']
```

Comment: How does it work? Is it a real chroot? Or maybe Python's chroot is just garbage? The idea of chroot is to remain in chroot forever.

Comment: @DamianNowak: as I explained in the answer, you need to `chdir` into the `chroot` for it to take effect. You also need to close file descriptors on outside directories. `chroot` is not a magic bullet, it should be used with care.

Answer (score 3):

Before chroot save a reference to current root directory as a file descriptor.

To return set current working directory to the file descriptor, then chroot to `.`.

Example python session:

```
$ unshare -r python3
Python 3.8.2 (default, Apr 27 2020, 15:53:34) 
[GCC 9.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import os
>>> f = os.open("/", os.O_PATH)
>>> os.chdir("/mnt")
>>> os.chroot(".")
>>> os.listdir(".")
[]
>>> os.listdir("/")
[]
>>> os.chdir(f)
>>> os.chroot(".")
>>> os.listdir("/")
['bin', 'lib', 'lib64', 'sbin', 'boot', 'btrfs', 'btrfs_ssd', 'cdrom', 'dev', 'etc', 'home', 'media', 'mnt', 'opt', 'proc', 'root', 'run', 'snap', 'srv', 'sys', 'tmp', 'usr', 'var', 'secure']
```

Alternatively leave the current working directory set to the old root directory.

Answer (score 1):

If you are running as root, another option is mounting `/proc` and exiting via `/proc/1/cwd/`. Example using shell commands:

```
whoami # Should be root
mount -t proc proc /proc
chroot /proc/1/cwd/ $SHELL
```

Answer (score -2):

Just save the current path before using Dir.chroot, using Dir.pwd

Comment: The string returned by `pwd` is useless after `chroot`, because it alters the filename lookup rules.